# How to resolve org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEMessage.close()V

Tags: java, rest, jersey, multipartform-data

We are working on a Java REST service which will consume multipart/form-data.

We need to upload a file and an XML payload in the same REST operation.

The following is our code:

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletName</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>        
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>package-name</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>       
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

**dependencies.gradle**

```
compile('org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:2.22.2')
    compile('org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:2.22.2')
```

**java changes**

```
@POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response upload(@Context HttpServletRequest request, 
            @Context UriInfo uriInfo,
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream in,
            @FormDataParam("s") String s){
```

...java code...
}

But when we try to upload a file and pass a String parameter to the REST operation via POSTMAN, it gives following exception:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEMessage.close&#40;&#41;V
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:278)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:509)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:102)
    ....
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:106)
    ...
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:106)
    ...
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEMessage.close&#40;&#41;V
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderClientSide.getMimeParts(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:276)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readMultiPart(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderServerSide.readMultiPart(MultiPartReaderServerSide.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:183)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1085)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:874)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:808)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:234)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider$ValueFactory.getEntity(FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider$FormDataMultiPartFactory.provide(FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider$FormDataMultiPartFactory.provide(FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.java:140)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.provide(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
```

Comment: Those aren't all your dependencies. It looks like you're using Spring also. Is there something else pulling in a different version of mimepull? Anytime you see a NoSuchMethodError, it's almost always an incompatible version of a dependency you are mixing.